# I'm having a problem using Firebase in Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

Unity 2021.3.16f1
firebase_unity_sdk_10.7.0

I am getting the following error while using firebase in unity.

The processor architecture "MSIL" of the project being built and the processor architecture "x86" of the reference "Firebase.App" do not match. This inconsistency can cause runtime errors. Change a project's target processor architecture through the configuration manager, such as by aligning the processor architecture between the project and the reference, or by using a dependency on a reference that has a processor architecture that matches the project's target processor architecture.

I'm going to build an Android version, and this is my configuration settings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI2eV.png)

I think I downloaded the latest version of Unity Firebase SDK.
And I guess Android build doesn't support 'x86'. so i don't know what to do...
Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried to rebuild Unity Firebase SDK, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify/ make sure before proceeding, in build settings have you selected android? [The platform selection should look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2WcU.png)

If you have, are you intending to build for x86 (most likely therefore for a desktop machine in a emulator or running in Chrome OS) or for ARM (for use on most mobile devices)?

Please make sure you have the appropriate boxes checked in [the target architecture setting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK1gX.png)

After making sure those are both set how you intend them to be, try rebuilding and report back.

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally checked. I solved it a few days ago, but I don't remember the solution which I used. Maybe it was the way you told me.